# How to configure Adaptive Sampling through IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configuring-adaptive-sampling-for-aspnet-core-applications), under "Configure sampling settings", we can configure adaptive sampling and also include or exclude certain types from sampling:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
{
    var builder = configuration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
    // For older versions of the Application Insights SDK, use the following line instead:
    // var builder = configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;

    // Using adaptive sampling
    builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:5);

    // Alternately, the following configures adaptive sampling with 5 items per second, and also excludes DependencyTelemetry from being subject to sampling.
    // builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:5, excludedTypes: "Dependency");

    // If you have other telemetry processors:
    builder.Use((next) => new AnotherProcessor(next));
    
    builder.Build();

    // ...
}
```

However, is there a way to do the same thing if we're configuring our application through `WebHostBuilder.Configure()` and passing in a delegate that takes an `IApplicationBuilder`?  In this situation, we wouldn't be able to obtain the `TelemetryConfiguration` through DI.

I need to do something similar as the above, but I've only got the `IApplicationBuilder` interface.  From the docs, it seems like I should use `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder`, but `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` says it's obsolete on .NET Core and also says it loads the instance from ApplicationInsights.config, which I don't even have.  I'm creating an entire AppInsights client from code.

I suppose another way to do it would be to create my own TelemetryProcessor that does sampling exactly the way I want, but this seems like overkill.  Basically I'd like to alter the configuration of the current `AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor` in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IApplicationBuilder` interface has an `ApplicationServices` property, which you can use to resolve `TelemetryConfiguration`. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
webHostBuilder.Configure(applicationBuilder =>
{
    var telemetryConfiguration = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices
        .GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>();

    // ...
});
```

This `TelemetryConfiguration` instance, which is registered as a singleton, is the same instance you're given when using `Startup.Configure`.